# Save Active Directory users in local database automatically - cron job

Tags: c#, performance, active-directory, asp.net-core-3.1

I want to create a scheduled job to save users from Active Directory to my local database, and check if there will be new users so this scheduled job will be executed automatically.

Note: `GetAllADUsers` in my startup file:

```
public void GetAllADUsers() 
{
    using (DirectorySearcher dssearch = new DirectorySearcher("LDAP://XXX", new string[] { "cn" })) 
    {
        dssearch.Filter = $"(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))";
        SearchResultCollection sresult = dssearch.FindAll();

        foreach (SearchResult srUsers in sresult)
        {
            AD_USERS.Add(
                new User
                {
                    Username = ((string)srUsers.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["cn"].Value)
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Note: `GetAllADUsers` is located in the startup file and it's working perfectly but it increases my project up to 2 minutes and 35 seconds to load.

Any ideas/help would be appreciated.

Thank you all

Comment: I assume your question is regarding performance improvement? Or is it regarding duplicates when daily job run

Comment: its related to the performance yes, that's why I think of saving the usernames from Active directory to my local SQL database in order to make the performance faster; and the schedule task is for checking new user names.

Comment: as far as performance is concerned, you can bulk insert using `SqlBulkCopy` into some staging table and then execute merge stored procedure to insert/update data based on username field into target table, merge in SQL is comparatively faster.